# How to kill application process?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin.Android application, I have code that handles restoring state after process death (when the OS kills the application to free memory). I want to test this code but I do not know how to simulate when my application process gets killed. I am trying to do it through the terminal. From my `platform-tools` folder:

```
drake@Drakes-MacBook-Pro platform-tools % ./adb shell
generic_x86:/ $ am kill com.mycompany.myapp
```

But this is not working. And I think it is because it is not targeting the OS in my emulator. I was expecting to see "Pixel_C_API_30" instead of "generic_x86". I am on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `adb device` command to list the device.

If you have multiple devices, you can use -s to specify the device XXX like this: `adb -s XXX shell`